# How to make a JSON skeleton and fill it in later

Tags: javascript, json, append

I am trying to make a JSON to store information about users. For example, in the end it want it to look like:

```
{
"people": [
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "company": "bar",
        "email": "foo@bar.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "company": "foo",
        "email": "bar@foo.com"
    }
]
}
```

This will be populated through a form, so I want to be able to declare an empty JSON and add on to it as people submit the form. Is there a way to declare an empty JSON with the skeleton (name, company, email)? Also how do i add on another entry? Is there some sort of .append("name": "bar", "company": "foo", "email": "bar@foo.com") ? I want to use straight javascript, but using jquery would be alright if needed.

Comment: What language? What library? You've omitted ***alot*** of important information from your question.

Comment: Using preferably straight javascript but using jquery would be acceptable

Comment: JSON is just JavaScript Object Notation. It's literally just a JavaScript object.

Comment: Do you want the end result to be just an object or a JSON string?

Answer (score 2):

With Javascript, there is no need to predefine anything in a JSON object.

This is perfectly valid code:

```
var o = {}; // create a new object

o.name = "Bob";
console.log(o.name); // prints Bob

o.scores = new Array();
o.scores[o.scores.length] = 1;
o.scores[o.scores.length] = 2;
o.scores[o.scores.length] = 3;
console.log(o.scores); // prints [1, 2, 3]

o.info = {};

o.info.isSet = true;
console.log(o.info.isSet); // prints true

console.log(o.info.isNotSet); // prints undefined
```

So you can dynamically build whatever type of JSON you need from your form.

If you want to then render the JSON as a string, you can use `JSON.stringify(o)`, and it will print:

```
{"name":"Bob","scores":[1,2,3],"info":{"isSet":true}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.Push`

```
var personInfo = {}; // Create the object and probably save it in 
  //localStorage or cookie etc or whatever pref you have, 
  //You can save it in `data` cache(of your HTML DOM element) too.

var peopleObj=[];
personInfo["people"] = peopleObj; //Save the array to the object onto the key/property "Person"

//Push the data as you need. 
peopleObj.push({"name":"whatever",
                 "company":"foo",
                 "email":"bar@foo.com"
               });

peopleObj.push({"name":"whatever2",
                "company":"foo",
                 "email":"bar@foo.com"});

console.log(personInfo);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DW7Av/)

Here is a sample Demo on what you might be trying to achieve:-
Using localStorage to store the skeleton and adding data on to it on button click.

### [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/d5tne/)

```
 var personInfo = {
      "people": []
  };

  window.localStorage.setItem('person',JSON.stringify(personInfo));
  var i = 0;
  $('input').click(function () {
     
      var obj = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('person'));
      obj["people"].push({
          "name": "whatever" + i++,
          "company": "foo",
          "email": "bar@foo.com"
      });
       window.localStorage.setItem('person',JSON.stringify(obj));
      console.log(obj);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a function to do your adding. It prevents you from needing to duplicate all of the addition code when adding a person to the list.

```
// define your object somewhere
var someObject = {
    "people": []
};

// define a function for adding to your main object
function addPerson(name, company, email) {
    someObject.people.push({
        "name": name,
        "company": company,
        "email": email
    });
}
```

Then, when you want to add another entry, just call the function:

```
addPerson("Some Name", "A Company", "person@website.com");
```

For for something like this, I'd say it's probably best to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like:

```
var Person = function (name, company, email)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.company = company;
    this.email = email;
}

var People = function ()
{
    this.people = [];

    this.add = function (person)
    {
        this.people.push(person);
    }
}

var people = new People();

people.add(new Person("john", "smith", "blah@blah.com"));

alert(JSON.stringify(people));
```